# Making ONE single JOB for 2 Separate SQL Agents running on SQL2008 and SQL 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Scenario:**

2 servers - SQL2008 and SQL2016

**Job 1 :** Backup - Scheduled SQL Agent Job running for 2 Databases on SQL2008 with the destination on SQL2016 server

**Job 2 :** Restore - Scheduled SQL Agent Job running for 2 Databases on SQL2016 from the that location.

So thinking of making these 2 individual into a single job for Backup and Restore.

Please help/guide me to combining these 2 Jobs.
Do I Use Powershell or SQL for getting this correct?

Comment: mysql is not sql server - don't spam tag your questions.

Answer (score 0):

When communicating between two servers, the best way I know is to create a [Linked Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql) going both-ways, and on each server. The only gotcha is to make sure the SQL syntax used to select or insert data from a server, is compliant with that server, or the `linked server`.

From [SQLShack](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-and-configure-a-linked-server-in-sql-server-management-studio/)...

"*Linked servers allow submitting a T-SQL statement on a SQL Server instance, which returns data **from other SQL Server instances**. A linked server allows joining data from several SQL Server instances using a single T-SQL statement when data exists on multiple databases on different SQL instances. By using a linked server to retrieve data from several SQL instances, the only thing that should be done is to connect to one SQL instance.
There are two ways of configuring linked server in SSMS. One way is by using sp_addlinkedserver system stored procedure and another is by using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) GUI interface.*"

Without writing out the SQL code for both backups and restores, I suggest you read up on Linked Servers, and apply them into your code. I recommend you test the code first manually, outside of a job, and then apply it to a scheduled job or [Maintenance Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/maintenance-plans/maintenance-plans).

But as a hint :), try the syntax when linking your table from a linked server object:

```
[LINKED SERVER].[DATABASE].[Schema].[TableName]
```